# @meditations.count works within folder but not in partial used elsewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

views/meditations/_count.html.erb

```
<p><small><%= @meditations.count %></small></p>
```

when I try using that on the home page like so:

```
<%= render partial: "/meditations/count" %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried to change the call to:

```
<%= render partial: "/meditations/count", object: @meditations %>
```

I finally got what I wanted but I'm thinking I violated some kind of law by doing this on the home page:

```
<p><%= Meditations.count %> </p>
```

What should I have done to get the partial working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the error:
>
> undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

Any time you see undefined ____ for nil class it is b/c you are calling blah on something that you think has value, but is nil. In other words, `@mediatations` is coming in as nil.

So check your controller. In the method that matches this page, make sure you have something like `@meditations = Meditation.all`.

Lastly, yes - `Meditations.count` is a call to the db from the view. Very bad practice. Basically breaking MVC.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Is there another way to do this, such as by declaring the variables within the call on the home page? (It's working so I'm not going to change it; just interested in knowing the alternate way. I've never seen instructions before that call for modifying the target controller in order to place a partial. Is it because it's a call for a count rather than a param?

Comment: The MVC way of doing it is to build up all your variables in your controller. The View is supposed to be as dumb as possible (no logic or calls). The controller is for business logic and heavy lifting. The Model is for accessing the database. 

Once you have mastered the above, look into Fat Model/Skinny Controller flow. It basically means taking a bunch of the logic in your controller and extracting it to Plain old Ruby objects in the Models folder